# Grep is giving wrong results

Tags: linux, shell, grep, buffer

Let say I have some files **(A_1.x, A_2.txt, A_3.txt)** in a directory **(files)**

This works correctly :

```
find files/ | grep ".txt" | while read -r file ; do   
     echo $file
done

--> Result:
files/A_1.txt
files/A_2.txt
files/A_3.txt
```

However, When I call another program within the loop, the greps results are modified:

```
find files/ | grep ".txt" | while read -r file ; do
     ... Other program here ...  
     echo $file
done

--> Result:
files/A_1.txt
files/A_2.txt
s/A_3.txt      #Error here
```

I think it's an issue related to the buffer but I have no idea how to fix this.
My "other program" is asking a user input "Enter to continue" many times. However, it is skipped since i'm calling it from my shell script.

Comment: Why do you need `grep`? Just use `find file/ -name '*.txt" | ...`

Comment: Depending on what you are doing in the loop, you could probably use find -exec as well

Comment: I removed the `grep` to use your solution using only `find`, but I still have the same issue (same results as before). It works as a stand-alone but with the other program it's not working

Comment: I fixed it by modifying my other program. I had to remove the user inputs "Enter to continue" because I was running out of ideas to fix it correctly.